# Shows blank view when loading view controller from StoryBoard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have a project which is already in App Store.

Now I need to add some more screens using storyboards to the project. The project was previously implemented using nib files.

I have created storyboard for the new view controller which I have added. When the view controller is called it comes up almost blank, none of the views which I have added for the controller are not showing up.

I have added below code how i'm loading the view controller from story board.

```
-(void)gotoEventsScreen
{
    EventsListViewController* eventsScreen = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"EventsScreen" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: eventsScreen animated:YES];
}
```

Note: I have made EventsListViewController as initialviewcontroller and it also has identifier.

I have also tried to load with identifier still it shows me the blank screen.

Comment: Have you linked the viewcontrollers correctly?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT yes, in the inspector i have given the custom class name and also the Identifier

Comment: just to check if you have a navigation controller issue (like broken chain), try to present modally your storyboard vc, just for test.

Comment: Have you given the storyboard ID? If not give a storyboard Id and then
`EventsListViewController* eventsScreen = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EventsScreen"];`
where "EventsScreen" is the storyboard ID

Comment: @HarikrishnanT yes I have already added StoryBoardID. But the issue is same

Comment: @CalinChitu I have checked the all the possible ways. But, It couldn't solve my problem

Comment: If you are using navigation controller, which view controller have you set as root viewcontroller?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT the root view controller is a another class which is not using storyboard

Comment: If you are switching to storyboard, I would advice to use storyboard completely. Mixing up xib's and story board will cause a lot of complexities.

Comment: Have you tried setting the EventsListViewController as the root view controller? Is it showing up properly?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT I have many view controllers now I can't convert all xibs to storyboard. For the newly added controllers I want to use storyboard. Do you think is this possible

Comment: This is possible, you can push a viewcontroller in storyboard even if you are using xib as a rootview controller. You can push/pop to and fro from xib and story board. Do a couple of checks: check if that method is even triggered and by making the storyboard view controller as root view controller check if it is showing up properly. Also cross check the nibname.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT i have checked all the name are fine.

Comment: It is loading if you set it as rootviewcontroller? What all are there in the viewcontroller that is appearing as blank? Check if there is any view overlapping the other views..

Comment: @HarikrishnanT after loading the view I have tried to print the count of the subviews in the self.view .. it always shows me 1… through I have more than 7 views on it

Comment: Have you added the storyboard to target membership of your app?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT It is already added to the target membership.

Comment: Your code segment is correct. So the problem has to be elsewhere. I was trying to figure out if it was any of the common mistakes caused. Sorry but can't figure out the problem. If you find any solution, please do answer your own question with it so that it can be helpful to others. I am sure it is some small mistake somewhere. I just tried out this and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT I to tried doing small examples but it is working there. In this project might be missing something… If I found a solution I will try to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there was some problem with my project base class view controller which consists the initWithCoder method which was not calling its super class method.